# Excel display all values that match selected cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of unique words in Sheet 1, Column A and on Sheet 2, Column A sentences in each row.

I want to display all the sentences on Sheet 1, Column C that include the word that is currently selected in Column A.

```
_a____ means the cell containing "a" is selected

Col A | Col B | Col C
_a____|       | A lovely house
this  |       | Throw a ball

Sheet 2
Col A
A lovely house
Making it rain
Throw a ball
```

So it should return sentences where the word is a match, not a letter and it shouldn't be case sensitive.

If I select the next cell with "this", Column C should list all the sentences with the word "this" in them.

Comment: Sounds neat. Have you tried anything or are you looking for someone to write you some code? I'm thinking a `for` loop through `Sheet2!A:A` and `instr()` would be the best approach unless `Range.Find()` works with a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

This works but does also returns sentences including word including your search word. E.g. if you search for "all" your last sentence would be a match.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim strSearch As String, strFirst As String
Dim rngCell As Range, rngSearch As Range
Dim lngRow As Long

On Error Resume Next

strSearch = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Selection(1)).Value

Set rngSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
Set rngCell = rngSearch.Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

lngRow = 1
If Not rngCell Is Nothing Then
    strFirst = rngCell.Address
    Do
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lngRow).Value = rngCell.Value
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Set rngCell = rngSearch.FindNext(after:=rngCell)
    Loop Until rngCell.Address = strFirst
End If
```

And, don't Forget "End Sub" at the end. For some reason I cannot make this part of the code snippet.

BTW: If you want to also resolve the above issue then you'd have to use REGEXP.